# Mostrando los datos que trae procedimiento almacenado a una vista ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Estoy tratando de mostrar lo que trae mi procedimiento almacenado y quiero mandarlo a la vista:

De esta manera lo envio :

```
 var Fechainicio = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "inicio" , 
            Value = FechaDesde

        };

        var FechaFinal = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "final",
            Value = FechaHasta

        };

        var empleadoid = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "emp",
            Value = 2393

        };

        var deduc = db.Database.SqlQuery<PlanillaController>("exec sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado @inicio, @final, @emp", Fechainicio, FechaFinal, empleadoid).ToList<PlanillaController>();
        ViewBag.deduc = deduc.ToList();
```

Ya en la vista viene así:

```
foreach (var Deduccionees in (IEnumerable<RecursosHumanos.Models.sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado_Result>)ViewBag.Deduc)
  {
    <th>@Deduccionees</th>
  }
```

Este es el error

```
{"No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RecursosHumanos.Controllers.PlanillaController]' al tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RecursosHumanos.Models.sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado_Result]'."}
```

este son lo datos que deberia traerme el procedimiento almacenado 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el sp:

```
create procedure sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado @inicio datetime, @final datetime, @emp int
as
select 
ded.DedId,
sum(ded.DetDedEmpValor),
emp.EmpId


from Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado ded
inner join Tbl_Deducciones tip
 on tip.DedId = ded.DedId
 inner join Tbl_Empleado emp
 on emp.EmpId = ded.EmpId
 where ded.DetDedEmpFecha >=  @inicio and 
 ded.DetDedEmpFecha <= @final and 
 ded.EmpId = @emp
 group by ded.DedId, emp.EmpId
```

Comment: en el controlador el viewbac se llama ViewBag.deduc y en la vista ViewBag.Deduc. Puede que tenga algo que ver con eso. Prueba y me dices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen dia.

En primer lugar, necesitamos saber un poco sobre tu procedimiento almacenado y los datos que este devuelve. Como por el momento no contamos con eso te planteo lo siguiente ya que veo tienes varios puntos malos en el codigo:

1. Asigna una clase generica con el formato del resultado de tu procedimiento almacenado. Suponiendo que tu procedimiento almacenado termine con un Select * from @table o que desde el inicio declares el resultado como una tabla. Ej:

   ```
    public class ClaseGenerica
      {
        public int ID_columnaEntero {get;set;}
        public DateTime columnaFecha {get;set;}
        public string columnaString {get;set;}
        //Y sigues colocando propiedades(columnas) con su tipo correspondiente de datos en 
        //base al resultado de tu procedimiento almacenado
     }
   ```

   En base al resultado de tu SP, tu clase podria que quedar asi:

   ```
   public class DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado
   {
     public int DedId {get;set;} //O si es string el codigo, lo cambias
     public decimal valor {get;set;} //como es una suma a ti te muestra valor, ya que no le asignaste nombre a la columna
     public string EmpId {get;set;} //O en su defecto el tipo de datos que es
   }
   ```

Luego haces todo lo que te escribi anteriormente esperando resolver tu problema.

---

2. Asigna los parametros necesarios para el SP y luego guarda el resultado en una lista del tipo claseGenerica:

**En tu caso, edito como deberia de quedar**

```
SqlParameter @Fechainicio = new SqlParameter(){
  ParameterName = "@Fechainicio",
  DbType = DbType.Datetime, //Tipo de datos
  Value = FechaDesde
};    

 SqlParameter @FechaFinal = new SqlParameter(){
  ParameterName = "@FechaFinal",
  DbType = DbType.Datetime, //Tipo de datos
  Value = FechaHasta
};

 SqlParameter @empleadoid = new SqlParameter(){
  ParameterName = "@empleadoid",
  DbType = DbType.String, //Tipo de datos o Int32 si es entero y le quitas las comillas al valor en Value
  Value = "2393"
};

object[] parametros = new object[] { @Fechainicio,@FechaFinal, @empleadoid};

List<ClaseGenerica> resultado = db.Database.SqlQuery<ClaseGenerica>("exec sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado @Fechainicio,@FechaFinal, @empleadoid", parametros).ToList();`

ViewBag.deduc = resultado;
```

3. Muestras el resultado en tu vista:

   ```
   foreach(var Deduccionees in Viewbag.deduc){
    <th>@Deduccionees.nombredePropiedad</th>
   }
   ```

Disculpa el formato del comentario, soy nuevo por aca. Saludos

Comment: buenas @Francisco Velásquez ya subi a mi pregunta mi procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Ahorita edito mi respuesta

Comment: Bro excelente muchas gracias , mira el 2393 es el código del empleado , pero mira que necesito que lo haga por cada empleado que le mande , osea que para el empleado 2393 muy bien todo , digamos que ocupo la del empleado 2390

Comment: Funcionara bien si eliminas el parametro del codigo de empleado EmpId  de tu SP y solo dejas el de fechas? Asi no te filtra por empleado y te devuelve todos los datos de todos los empleados en base al rango de fechas. Luego, teniendo toda la lista en  de tu clase generica, lo ordenas o agrupas o haces lo que necesitas con ella.

Comment: Brother sabes como solucionar este ERROR : {"Otro SqlParameterCollection ya contiene SqlParameter."}  ,  estoy usando  SP y me tira ese error con el

Comment: Mmmm estas limpiando el command que usa los parametros? Es decir un:
command.Parameters.Clear();  luego de utilizar el sqlcommand?

Comment: No , no sabia de ese command.Parameters.Clear() , donde lo tendria que poner entonces en lo que ayudaste , o eso va en el otro que estoy usando

Comment: mmmm donde te esta generando exactamente ese error? Ya hiciste el proceso paso a paso de visual studio para identificar donde se dispara? Si no es asi, hazlo y comparte captura o el bloque de codigo para ver que pueda estar pasando, de ser necesario, habre una nueva pregunta(ya que esta fue marcada como contestada) y me avisas.

Comment: ya formula otra pregunta : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/208556/error-otro-sqlparametercollection-ya-contiene-sqlparameter

Comment: Bro @Francisco Velásquez sabes como pasar parametros de un vista a un controlador ?

Comment: Hola @MarcoEufragio , claro que si. Necesitas ayuda en algo?

Comment: Queria consultarte que tanto conocimiento tienes en DATATABLE , No se si esta puedes consultar esta pregunta : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887620/use-of-columndefs-and-footercallback-datatable

Answer (score 1):

Deberrias definir el mismo tipo de datos en el action y la view

```
@var lista = (List<RecursosHumanos.Models.PlanillaController>)ViewBag.Deduc;
@foreach (var Deduccionees in lista)
{
    <th>@Deduccionees</th>
}
```

si en el action defines `PlanillaController` en la view debes definir lo mismo, veras en el cast que realizo se usa la misma clase

No se de donde sacaste en la view el uso de `sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado_Result` si al realizas el `SqlQuery` no casteas a este tipo de dato

Comment: el sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado_Result es mi procedimiento almacenado , necesito llevar los datos que trae a la view , no se si esa es la mejor forma.  puedes ayudarme a llevar lo esta trayendo

Comment: bien, pero entonces porque casteas a tipos diferentes? sino en el SqlQuery deberias usar sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado_Result

Comment: como tendría que hacerlo entonces, porque necesito mostrar todo lo que me trae el Stored Procedure  : sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado_Result