# ERROR : Otro SqlParameterCollection ya contiene SqlParameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Estoy utilizando SqlParameter , al momento de usarlo dos veces me tira este error :

```
{"Otro SqlParameterCollection ya contiene SqlParameter."}
```

aquí lo utilizo la primera vez :  SP2

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db1 = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {
                        SqlParameter Fechainicio = new SqlParameter()
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@Fechainicio",
                            DbType = DbType.DateTime, //Tipo de datos
                            Value = @ViewBag.PlaFechaInicio
                        };

                        SqlParameter FechaFinal = new SqlParameter()
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@FechaFinal",
                            DbType = DbType.DateTime, //Tipo de datos
                            Value = @ViewBag.PlaFechaFin
                        };

                        SqlParameter empleadoid = new SqlParameter()
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@empleadoid",
                            DbType = DbType.String, //Tipo de datos o Int32 si es entero y le quitas las comillas al valor en Value
                            Value = item.EmpId
                        };

                        object[] parametros = new object[] { Fechainicio, FechaFinal, empleadoid };


                        List
                        <DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado>
                            resultado = db1.Database.SqlQuery<DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado>
                                ("exec sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado @Fechainicio,@FechaFinal, @empleadoid", parametros).ToList();


                        List<DetalleDeduccionesEmpleadoTotal> total = db1.Database.SqlQuery<DetalleDeduccionesEmpleadoTotal>("exec sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado @Fechainicio,@FechaFinal, @empleadoid", parametros).

                             ViewBag.deduc = resultado;''
```

aquí lo utilizo por segunda vez con algunos parámetros del anterior :SP1

```
SqlParameter inicio = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@inicio",
                DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                Value = FechaDesde
            };
            SqlParameter final = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@final",
                DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                Value = FechaHasta
            };
            SqlParameter areID = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@areID",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = Area.AreId
            };
            SqlParameter ageID = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@ageID",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = Agencia.AgeId
            };

            object[] parametros = new object[] { inicio, final, areID, ageID };

            List
                   <DeduccionesNombre> NombreD = db.Database.SqlQuery<DeduccionesNombre>("exec sp_DeduccionesNombre @inicio,@final,@areID,@ageID", parametros).ToList();

            ViewBag.duduccionesN = NombreD;
```

Comment: Son 2 procesos separados o todo se muestra en una misma vista?

Comment: eso esta en el mismo controlador y los resultados van a la misma vista , sin dos procesos diferentes SP 1 Y SP 2 , Pero  uno usa algunos paramatros del otro !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en que no puedes utilizar 2 veces los mismos parametros en este bloque:

```
List<DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado>resultado = db1.SqlQuery<DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado>
("exec sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado @Fechainicio,@FechaFinal, @empleadoid",parametros).ToList();


List<DetalleDeduccionesEmpleadoTotal> total = db1.Database.SqlQuery<DetalleDeduccionesEmpleadoTotal>("exec 
sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado @Fechainicio,@FechaFinal, @empleadoid", parametros).
```

Es decir, "total" quiere utilizar los mismos parametros de "resultado" lo cual no es valido. Trata agregando otros parametros para ese SP.

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias bro

Comment: bro , pero voy ocupar usar otros SP con esos mismos parámetros o similares como podría hacer en ese caso

Comment: Si esta en la misma vista, tendrias que hacer siempre diferentes parametros. Si es en diferentes vistas, no te dara problema.

Comment: Buenas @Francisco Velásquez conoces otra forma de hacer esto mismo , otra forma de enviar paramtros sql y traer los resultados y mostrarlos en la vista , la forma que me ayudaste esta perfecto. pero queria saber si conoces otra forma

Comment: Hola buen dia, pues fijate que normalmente yo trabajo con entity framework y linq, con lo que me ahorro bastantes pasos ,y ademas,  si hay otras formas de hacer eso, la idea es que hagas la que mas se acople a tu necesidad